# How to return elements from x to y in a Vec<T>?

Tags: vector, indexing, rust, range, slice

I have a `Vec` of structs and I want to get the ones from position x to y:

```rust
fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct A {
        name: String,
    }
    
    let x = A { name: "X".to_string() };
    let y = A { name: "Y".to_string() };
    let z = A { name: "Z".to_string() };
    
    let v = vec!(x,y,z);
    
    println!("{:?}", v[0..1]);
}
```

Here's the [Rust Playground link for it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0429db875911286ea8b1ad4d62f2d95).

I'm getting the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[A]` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:13:5
    |
13  |     println!("{:?}", v[0..1]);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

How can I make sure the size is known at compile time? I couldn't find any obvious answer, therefore I think I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```rust
println!("{:?}", v[0..1]);
```

To

```rust
println!("{:?}", &v[0..1]);
```

Indexing a `Vec` with a `Range` returns a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) which is sized, but when you use `[]` on a variable the compiler automatically dereferences the returned value (it's just syntax sugar), which in this case makes the slice unsized, so you have to put a reference in front of it to make it sized again.

See also:

- [Rust doesn't have a size known at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60162532/2766908)
- [What is the return type of the indexing operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161/2766908)